# Spring MVC java application is not displaying error logs in controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC application. In HTML, I have given the  action /signup/add as below,

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/signup/add" role="form"     id="createaccountform" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="user.username" class="form-control">
        </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create   Account</button>  &nbsp; 
      </form>
```

Below is the controller program

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addUser(@ModelAttribute("graphStory") GraphStory graphStory) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView;
    log.info("inside controller");
    log.debug("Inside Controller");
    System.out.println("Inside Controller");
    try {
        graphStory = graphStoryInterface.getUserInterface().save(graphStory);

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(graphStory.getErrorMsgs())) {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/msg");

            modelAndView.addObject("msg", "Thank you, " + graphStory.getUser().getUsername());
        } else {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/mustache/html/home/index.html");
            modelAndView.addObject("title", "Home");
            modelAndView.addObject(graphStory.getErrorMsgs());
        }
        return modelAndView;

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

When I am deploying the spring MVC from eclipse into tomcat and on click of buttton sign up, I am getting below error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /signup/add

type Status report

message /signup/add

description The requested resource is not available.
```

I am not sure what is the problem and I dont know why it is not printing my logs also.

I am using spring version 4.0.5 and mustacheJS as javascript templating library.

can anybody help me on this. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Your action is wrong... You are posting to `/signup/add` whereas you should post to `<context-root>/signup/add` assuming that your application isn't deployed as the root application.

Comment: what should be my context root and how to identify that.

Answer (score 0):

Your action should be.

```
action="signup/add"
```

And if you are looking logs in server you can  enable the logs in log4j properties like below

```
log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL
```

Hope this helps.